# Test Django Forms submitted through Ajax view

Tags: python, json, django

I I'm trying to test a view that is used by Ajax. While with the server (manual testing) everything works, when I ran my unit test an error I can't explain appears.

If you take a look at the following lines, where I present my code the most simplified as possible, you will see that although I add a variable to the json dict named something (just as I do in ajax) the field appears as missing in the form.

#### My Test (`tests.py`):

```
def test_edit_profile_user(self):
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(
        username='user', email='test@awesome.org', password='top_secret')
    self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password='top_secret')

    data = {'something': 'data'}
    response = self.client.post(reverse('edit_something'),
                                json.dumps(data),
                                content_type='application/json',
                                HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')

    print(response.content)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

While my Ajax view works, my test gives the following traceback:

```
b'{"something": ["This field is mandatory."]}'

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***\tests.py", line 81, in ***
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 400 != 200
```

What am I doing wrong in the test?

### The rest of the code:

#### My view (`views.py`):

```
def edit_something(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            response_code = 200
            response_data = {'something':'updated')

        else:
            response_code = 400
            response_data = form.errors

        return JsonResponse(
            response_data,
            status=response_code,
        )
```

#### My JS (`something.js`):

```
$.ajax({
    url : form_endpoint, // the endpoint
    type : "POST", // http method
    data : {
        something: 'data',
    },// data sent with the post request
```

And code to handle the response

Answer (score 2):

I hope I get a better solution, but for now, my solution was to remove `content_type` and post a dictionary.

In `tests.py` the code for the var `response` is:

```
  response = self.client.post(reverse('edit_something'), data)
```

This makes the view receive the appropriate values, while when I add `content_type='application/json'` the view `request.POST` is empty.